# How to define Error schema using Spring Boot Open API 3?

Tags: swagger-2.0, openapi

I am using **Spring Boot and Spring Rest** Application. In this example I am migrating from Swagger2 to Open API 3.

I've below `@APiResponse` which returns 500 errors code and I define the ErrorResource Object for the same. I am not sure how to define error schema in this annatation for the same ?

```
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "For Success"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error") })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the schema implementation of your ErrorDetails on the content attribute.
For exampel:

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
        schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDetails.class)))
```

You can have a look at the swagger documentation:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the **SpringFox** dependency:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = "200", message = "For Success"),
    @ApiResponse(code = "500", message = "Internal Server Error", response = MyErrorResponse.class)
})
```